# How can I grant mailbox permissions with PowerShell so that each member in a group has Full Access to every other member of the group?

Tags: email, permissions, powershell, exchange

I'm faced with the task of granting Full Access and Send As permissions on a large group of customer service representatives. I want each member (of a distribution group) to have Full Access and Send As rights to the mailboxes of *every other* member of that group, but not themselves.

It's possible through using the Add-MailboxPermission cmdlet on a one-to-one basis, but this group has hundreds of users and it's not practical to be done this way. Plus, I want to better understand PowerShell in the process.

We have Exchange Online through Office 365 and can modify our instance through MSOL/Azure AD PowerShell connections.

Comment: Hi there!  We're not a script writing-service, please show us what you've researched and attempted already, and tell us exactly where you're gtting stuck. Here's some partial pseudo code to get you pointed in a direction for you studies.... ;)  `$members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -id "MyGroup"` (new line) `ForEach ($member in $member) { Add-MailboxPermission -Id $member }`

Comment: I can see a use case for shared access, but part of your description threw me: I want each member to have Full Access to the mailboxes of every other member of that group, **but not themselves**.   Can you clarify that part?

Comment: @Techie007 Thank you for your direction!

Comment: @fixer1234 I should clarify. The users already have full access to their own mailboxes, so I was trying to say that I wanted them 'skipped' from the permission adds because they already possessed them. Sorry for the confusion.